# Adding rows dynamically to an html table with no rows

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am using this to add a row dynamically to a table:

```
   $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>');
```

but it doesn't seem to work if the table has no records:

```
<table id="myTable" class="altTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Col1
            </th>
            <th>
                Col2
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what would be the right selector here to add a row that would work if there are 0 or > 0 rows existing ?

Comment: Do you want to add the row to end of tbody?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("<tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>").appendTo("#myTable tbody");
```

That should add a row to the end of the table body tag regardless of if there are rows there already or not.

If the tbody tag won't be present w/o any rows already there then you would do this...

```
if ($("#myTable tbody").length > 0){
  $("<tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>").appendTo("#myTable tbody");
}
else{
  $("<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr></tbody>").appendTo("#myTable");
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me in IE8. Basically, it results in this HTML: "<TR> 1</TD><//TD> <TD> </TD> a</TD><//TD></TR><//TR> </TR>" Idea? Thanks.

Comment: sure, I posted the issue here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329319/javascript-issue-when-dynamically-adding-a-row-from-its-html-to-a-table-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !$('#myTable tbody').length )
{
  $('#myTable').append( $('<tbody>') );
}

$('#myTable tbody').append( '<tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>' );
```

Comment: I think this won't add rows to the inner of thead or tbody.